# context error in RecyclerVIew Adapter onBIndVIewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

here is my Adapter code in which i get error in adapter method onBindViewHolder
cannot resolve getTitle(),getGenre(),getYear()

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context;
List<Movie> moviesList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    }
}

public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movieList) {
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.context = context;
}

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());//error here as cannot resolve getTitle
    holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());//error here as cannot resolve getGenre
    holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());//error here as cannot resolve getYear
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}


}
```

here is my Movie class file
    public class Movie {
    private String title, genre, year;

```
public Movie() {
}

public Movie(String title, String genre, String year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have imported android.graphics.Movie instead of your own Movie class in you adapter.
Also, as @rob said you have getTitle1() method, not getTitle()

Comment: yes i have imported android.graphics.movies thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

It could be an error in your onBindViewHolder method, instead:

```
holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
```

try:

```
holder.title.setText(movie.get(position).getTitle());
```

Overall:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(movie.get(position).getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(movie.get(position).getYear());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your Movie has getTitle1() but no getTitle() look:

```
....
public Movie(String title, String genre, String year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
}

public String getTitle1() {
    return title;
}
...
```

Comment: nope that's just my small mistake i done during trial and error thats not the case sorry i edited that